# Android - Possible to fade icon within a floatingbutton?

Tags: android, icons, fade, floating-action-button

I would like to know if it is possible to fade out the icon within a button, and when that fading is done, fade in a new icon. All buttons used are FloatingActionButtons.

Now, my "solution" is that 
I have two buttons, one that is visible before click, let us call that the *searchButton*. The other one is shown after click, let us call that one *backButton*. Both buttons are positioned in the same space, the lower left corner. The backButton is set to be invisible.

This is the searchButton, and this is shown as default.

[image: searchButton]

This is the backButton, and this is shown after searchButton is pressed and has translated.

[image: backButton]
I have an animation that translates the searchButton to the middle of the screen, and then fades out the searchButton. At the same time, I have the same translation animation to the backButton, but I fade it in instead.

This works, but not exactly as I would like to. Now, in the middle of the path between the two endpoints, a button is not really visible. This is because it is the point where searchButton is entirely faded out and backButton is just starting to fade in.

To clarify, here is a picture that shows the button in the middle of its path.

[image: inBetween]

I don't really mind that the icons look mixed, but I don't like that the button is fading.

I would be pleased to provide code, but I'm not sure what code that is interesting here. Please ask and I will provide the necessary bits.

Upon request, this is the onClick-method I have for my button.

```
public void goToSearch(View view){
    floatingSearchButton = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.searchRecipe);
    rotateForward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_roll_to_right);
    rotateBackward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_roll_from_right);




    floatingAddButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    floatingAddButton.setAlpha(1.0f);

    if(!flagValue){
        editText.animate().alpha(1.0f).translationY(-783f).translationX(110f).setDuration(500);
        editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //floatingAddButton.animate().translationX(70f).setDuration(500);
        floatingAddButton.startAnimation(rotateForward);
        floatingSearchButton.animate().alpha(0.0f).translationY(-777f).translationX(85f).setDuration(500);

        floatingBackButton.animate().alpha(1.0f).translationY(-777f).translationX(85f).setDuration(500);
        floatingBackButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        floatingSearchButton.bringToFront();
        floatingBackButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_undo_white_24dp);
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                boolean handled = false;
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    //goToSearchResults(view)
                    handled = true;
                }
                return handled;
            }
        });
        rotateForward.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                floatingAddButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        flagValue = true;

    } else {
        /*roll in the add button again
        and roll out the editText again
         */
        editText.animate().alpha(0.0f).translationY(0f).translationX(0f).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });
        floatingAddButton.startAnimation(rotateBackward);
        rotateBackward.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                floatingAddButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        hideKeyboard(this);
        floatingSearchButton.animate().alpha(1.0f).translationY(0f).translationX(0f);
        floatingBackButton.animate().alpha(0.0f).translationY(0f).translationX(0f);
        //floatingSearchButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search_white_24dp);
        flagValue = false;
    }
```

This is the XML for the buttons.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/searchRecipe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#ffeb3b"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:onClick="goToSearch"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/goBack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#ffeb3b"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:onClick="goToSearch"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    />
```

Comment: provide your code and we might would able to help you

Comment: There you go, I hope that will do.